# libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so in CentOS system

Tags: linux, centos, driver

After I install the chimera. I failded to run the program with the error show below

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/i965_dri.so: undefined symbol: drm_intel_get_reset_stats)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: drm_intel_get_reset_stats)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadCurrentWindow
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  1371
  Current serial number in output stream:  1371
```

I am using the Thinkpad E430. CentOS6.3 . I am not so familiar with the Linux system. But it seems to be the problem of Intel Integrate Graphic driver? Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thanks. If you need more info , please dont be hesitate to ask....

Comment: I have the same problem on debian jessie, with intel HD 5500. I installed the drives and cinnamon is using GL correctly but when i try create a freeglut3 program i get this error when my program runs.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505566/1256697