# Android Studio Run Emulator Failed on linux

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm tried to run the Android Emulator from Android Studio 2.3.3 (On linux machine) but if fails with no error (I try with a x86 image API 24).

So I try to run from console

```
 /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator @Nexus_5_API_24
```

and I get this error

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
```

I found out [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213192) that running with `-use-system-libs` option solves the problem

My question is how can I add this parameter to run the emulator via Android Studio? 
How can I start my app from Android Studio on the emulator that I run from terminal? 
Now I recieved this error:

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: Try to disable the video acceleration for this emulator, this seems to be an issue on your system

Comment: How can I disable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator in Yakkety Yak (Ubuntu 16.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066007/android-emulator-in-yakkety-yak-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: Ideal solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142335/3647002

Answer (score 5):

Problem cause of Android-Studio Driver which is shipped with the Software.
Do this to replace it by the os-driver (for me on Manjaro-Linux [kind of Arch-Linux]:

```
mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}
mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18{,.bak}
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so  ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/
```

For older Android-Studio versions, the libstdc++ lay in another directory (named tools instead emulator).
*For this use:*

```
mv ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}
mv ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18{,.bak}
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so  ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/
```

Comment: This worked just fine, except I had libstdc++.so.6.0.19 instead.